# What is the hourly pay for TA/RA at good math PhD programs in the U.S.?

Tags: teaching-assistant

I'm interested in the first tier (the top six programs e.g. MIT and UCB) and the second tier (the next ten programs e.g. Columbia and Caltech) math PhD programs in the U.S. According to the [link](http://math.mit.edu/academics/grad/financial/index.php), MIT's math dept. pays $3,050 monthly to a TA who works for 12 hours per week. Since I'm an int'l student, I can work for another 8 hours per week in this case. Since this TA job may cover a part of the tuition and fee (40k~50k) as well, working for an extra hour may increase the pay at the rate higher than $56/h(=$3,050/55), assuming that I work for 55 hours per week.

I'm sure the difference in pay scale between each program is large, but I'd appreciate if you could give me the answer for any program of the above type you're familiar with regarding the approximate hourly pay for a TA job above the required minimum length.

Comment: In my experience, although 12 hours per week may be the *typical* workload, the contracts are usually written based on a nominal 20 hours per week.  As such, I don't think you are allowed to take another job at all.  The page at http://web.mit.edu/iso/immigration/emp_campus.shtml confirms this.

Comment: I'm not familiar with MIT, but I'm surprised they're that generous.  In any case, I don't see why want to factor in tuition coverage or want to know this.  What's relevant is knowing how much TA duties are expected and how much you actually make (not counting tuition waivers).

Comment: Also, I don't know why you divided a monthly salary by a number of hours per week.

Comment: So yeah, the upshot is that you can't earn more money by working additional hours, neither by taking on more TA duties nor by getting a second job.  The "hourly pay" is irrelevant.

Comment: I graduated there a couple years ago, and these guys have it right: $3050/mo (up $500 since I started, wow) is the salary no matter how many hours you actually teach, and even if you advisor buys you out for a semester.  You're not supposed to take other jobs.  The one exception is during the summer, when you can either teach or work off campus somewhere.

Comment: I see. Then, the things got much simpler. I appreciate clarification a lot! Kimball, I did so, because I thought I would get $55 for each extra hour of TA-ing if the stipulated amount of stipend is what one gets for the standard TA work. Now I know I was wrong.

Comment: And just to clarify, as mentioned above, all the tuition, fees, and health insurance are covered as well, but that money doesn't really count as salary (and in particular is not taxable, except the insurance).  I think this is probably the case at all the programs you mention.

Comment: @Math.StackExchange Let me also add that trying to work to make extra money during your PhD is probably a [false economy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_economy). You should be doing everything you can to make yourself the most employable person you can post-PhD, because this is going to lead to larger rewards in terms of job opportunities and greater earning power than making a few bucks here and there earning an hourly wage part-time. Better to just focus on your studies and use any extra time to be publishing more research. The only exception is if you teach a class for experience.

Comment: Maybe I should also note, I knew a guy who was interested in liberal arts jobs and so took a position adjuncting at a nearby college for one semester.  (At MIT, as various other programs, a grad student can't get experience as the instructor of a record for a course.)  Nobody from the administration ever hassled him about it, but I think they just didn't know.

Comment: Shane, you're totally right. I will definitely do as you suggested. Mark, that's interesting. I didn't know that it's possible.

Comment: @Mark presumably that student was not an international student on a student visa, though.

Comment: @ff524 This is true, good point.

Comment: @Mark Can you turn these comments into an answer, so that I can vote it up?